# Event receiver (type documents) fires for almost everything, including new usergroups, new sites etc

Tags: document-library, event-handlers

I have created an event receiver with the "documents" as templateid (101).

```
 <Receivers ListTemplateId ="101">
```

When I upload a document, the event gets fired. So no problem here. However the event also fires when I create a new usergroup, a new site etc..

I only want it to fire when a user uploads a document. What am I doing wrong, and how can I make sure that it only triggers for a 'real document (all filetypes)

Background info : The event receiver sets userrights on a document

**Elements.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Receivers ListTemplateId ="101">
<Receiver>
<Name>SetSecurityOnItemItemAdded</Name>
<Type>ItemAdded</Type>
<Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
<Class>MSH_SetSecurityOnItem.SetSecurityOnItem.SetSecurityOnItem</Class>
<SequenceNumber>1000</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
<Receiver>
<Name>SetSecurityOnItemItemUpdated</Name>
<Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
<Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
<Class>MSH_SetSecurityOnItem.SetSecurityOnItem.SetSecurityOnItem</Class>
<SequenceNumber>1000</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
</Receivers>
</Elements>
```

**FEATURE.XML**

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"         Title="MSH_SetSecurityOnItem Feature" Description="MSH_SetSecurityOnItem Feature"     Id="52d11a53-c336-4446-abc0-a38d57b18704" Scope="Site">
  <Properties>
    <Property Key="ConfigFile" Value="SecurityConfig.xml" />
    <Property Key="ConfigSchemaFile" Value="SecurityConfig.xsd" />
  </Properties>
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="SetSecurityOnItem\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="SetSecurityOnItem\SecurityConfig.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="SetSecurityOnItem\SecurityConfig.xsd" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**ITEMUPDATED**

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {        
            if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
            {
                //This is when the update event is triggered by check-in.
            }
            else //This is triggered by events other than check-in action. 
            {              
                //Get configuration from feature
                Guid featureGuid = new Guid("52d11a53-c336-4446-abc0-a38d57b18704");
                SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
                SPSite site = properties.OpenSite();
                SPFeature feature = site.Features[featureGuid]; //web.Features[featureGuid];
                string ConfigFile = @"SetSecurityOnItem\" + feature.Properties["ConfigFile"].Value;
                string SchemaFile = @"SetSecurityOnItem\" + feature.Properties["ConfigSchemaFile"].Value;
                string ConfigFilePath = Path.Combine(feature.Definition.RootDirectory, ConfigFile);
                string ConfigSchemaFilePath = Path.Combine(feature.Definition.RootDirectory, SchemaFile);

                Trace.WriteLine("Current sitename is : " + web.Title);
                Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + properties.ListItem.Name + " started Event Handler ItemUpdated");

                //make sure that the config file exists
                Trace.WriteLine(ConfigFilePath.ToString());
                if (File.Exists(ConfigFilePath))
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Config file exists");

                    // create the datatable
                    dt = new DataSet();

                    //load the configuration into an XMLReader
                    using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(File.OpenRead(ConfigFilePath)))
                    {
                        dt.ReadXmlSchema(ConfigSchemaFilePath);
                        dt.ReadXml(rdr);
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Security config file contains {0} rows", dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString()));
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Security config file contains {0} columns", dt.Tables[0].Columns.Count.ToString()));
                    }

                    //pass the table to the SetSecurty method to do the real work
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "The chosen security class for this item = {0}", properties.ListItem["Machtigingen"].ToString().Substring(1, 1)));

                     // this is were the magic starts
                     SetSecurityStores(properties, dt, properties.ListItem["Machtigingen"].ToString().Substring(1, 1));
                     SetSecurityHolding(properties, properties.ListItem["Machtigingen Holding"].ToString().Substring(1, 1));

                }
                else
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Config file DOES NOT exist");
                    //TO DO Error message
                }

                base.ItemUpdated(properties);
                web.Dispose();
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Please add the declarative code you are using

Comment: Hi, I added the code

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [ListTemplateId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) enumeration, it specifies that the 106 would be for Calendars. So according to this, I would take the 101.
Further explanations on the registration on events can be found on msdn: [Event Registrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460929.aspx)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. It was my mistake. I used 101. For testing I also tried differend ID's.

Comment: My bad. It should be 101. I did some tests with other id's . However the problem still exists. Then even if I use 106, it is also fired when creating usergroups etc.. so in this case not only for calendars.

Comment: Could you please show the whole event receiver XML definition to see if there's something wrong...

Comment: Elements.xml code added to my original post

Comment: I found something out today. It seems that when a features as a scope"site" it ignores the templateID and just fires for every list. What is the best way to deal with this ? I need it to fire for every document library in a lot of sites (within the sitecollection) so scope"web"is not an option for me I think.

Comment: Have you tried using ListUrl instead of TemplateId? Alternatively use a Web scoped feature and activate the feature in your web template or staple it to your site definition. I remember having similar issues, but I dont have access to the box where i experienced this right now